# How to filter input data and pass to AWS step function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

One of the step in the step function outputs a list of objects. I want to filter the list based on `Status` and store the objects in separate files in s3 (e.g. file with list of objects with success vs. failed). Is there a way to filter the data in the step function? Or do I have to create a lambda to filter the data and then, create another lambda to write each filter list of objects to s3?

Input:

```
[{
 Name: "Test 1",
 Status: "Success",
 Data: {...}
},
{
 Name: "Test 2",
 Status: "Success",
 Data: {...}
},
{
 Name: "Test 3",
 Status: "Failed",
 Data: {...}
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you are going to process the list of objects split into 2 piles at the same time.
[image]

### Filtering with JSONPath Syntax

You can use a filter expression with [JSONPath](https://goessner.net/) syntax for your case. It indeed has [some limitations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-paths.html#amazon-states-language-reference-paths) currently yet in your scenario, this filtering expression, `$[?(@.Status==Success)]`, shall work for you.

- `$`: Refers to the root of the JSON document.
- `[ ]`: Square brackets indicate that we are working with an array.
- `?()`: A filter expression, denoted by a question mark and parentheses. It is used to apply a condition to the elements within the array.
- `@`: Refers to the current element in the array.
- `.Status`: Accesses the `Status` property of the current element.
- `==Success`: This is the condition that must be true for the element to be included in the result. It checks if the `Status` property of the current element is equal to the string 'Success'.

### Data Flow Simulator Results

This is the result of checking the filtering expressions using the **data flow simulator** available in AWS Step Functions.
[image: Success filtering]
[image: Failed filtering]

### Minimal ASL Reference

```json
{
  "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
  "StartAt": "Some compute progress",
  "States": {
    "Some compute progress": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Parameters": {
        "Payload.$": "$",
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-northeast-1:123456789012:function:some-compute-progress:$LATEST"
      },
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "Lambda.ServiceException",
            "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
            "Lambda.SdkClientException",
            "Lambda.TooManyRequestsException"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 2,
          "MaxAttempts": 6,
          "BackoffRate": 2
        }
      ],
      "Next": "Parallel"
    },
    "Parallel": {
      "Type": "Parallel",
      "End": true,
      "Branches": [
        {
          "StartAt": "Process success",
          "States": {
            "Process success": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
              "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
              "Parameters": {
                "Payload.$": "$",
                "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-northeast-1:123456789012:function:process-objects-expert:$LATEST"
              },
              "Retry": [
                {
                  "ErrorEquals": [
                    "Lambda.ServiceException",
                    "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
                    "Lambda.SdkClientException",
                    "Lambda.TooManyRequestsException"
                  ],
                  "IntervalSeconds": 2,
                  "MaxAttempts": 6,
                  "BackoffRate": 2
                }
              ],
              "End": true,
              "InputPath": "$[?(@.Status==Success)]"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "StartAt": "Process failed",
          "States": {
            "Process failed": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
              "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
              "Parameters": {
                "Payload.$": "$",
                "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-northeast-1:123456789012:function:process-objects-expert:$LATEST"
              },
              "Retry": [
                {
                  "ErrorEquals": [
                    "Lambda.ServiceException",
                    "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
                    "Lambda.SdkClientException",
                    "Lambda.TooManyRequestsException"
                  ],
                  "IntervalSeconds": 2,
                  "MaxAttempts": 6,
                  "BackoffRate": 2
                }
              ],
              "End": true,
              "InputPath": "$[?(@.Status==Failed)]"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### References

1. Beswick, J. (2021) *Using JSONPath effectively in AWS Step Functions, AWS Compute Blog*. © 2023, Amazon Web Services, Inc. or its affiliates. Available at: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-jsonpath-effectively-in-aws-step-functions/ (Accessed: April 7, 2023).
2. Liszi (no date) *Step functions Filter support for jsonpath - feature request, AWS re:Post*. Available at: https://repost.aws/questions/QUkLTFPfR7TwqEo4JD_Lvh7w/step-functions-filter-support-for-jsonpath-feature-request (Accessed: April 7, 2023).